# Mysqli_real_escape_string vulnerable

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

So I was busy with PHP, inserting data into mysql when I wanted to know: I have come accross some posts that say it's bad practice to use single quotes to insert data into a database. one of the examples: [Why are VALUES written between quotes when sent to a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681986/why-are-values-written-between-quotes-when-sent-to-a-database?noredirect=1#comment88450866_50681986)
The post is about why they're written between quotes, but one thing was clear: It's bad practice to insert it like:

```
$sql = INSERT INTO example (example1, example2, example3) VALUES 
('$example1', '$example2', '$example3');
```

Why is this be bad practice? Apparently it is vurnerable to injection as stated in the above link given. the OP his question was related to the comment was: We use `mysqli_real_escape_string` for this. The respons given was:

> @XX To a large extent, yes, it is an alternative solution to the problem. It doesn't disable anything, but it escapes things so that for instance ' becomes '' or \' in the SQL string, keeping the attacker from ending the string. There are awkward cases where such escaping is hard, and it's easy to miss one escape call among many, which is why parametrised queries are considered the most reliable approach.

First of all: How does a script want to fool `mysqli_real_escape_string` into NOT escaping certain stuff? I found something that said the following and correct me if i'm wrong: [mysqli_real_escape_string - example for 100% safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052328/mysqli-real-escape-string-example-for-100-safety). As you can see he refers to another page, that has an answer. However He then makes a claim that should make his data 100% safe and someone else responds with:

> Yes, that is generally safe. Mysql and mysqli are perfectly safe when used right (specific bugs in very specific encodings notwithstanding). The advantage of prepared statements is that it's more difficult to do things the wrong way.

I have the following example to make it clear for myself: I have 2 doors, 1 door is open, but behind a closed door. How would you attack an open door with a closed door in front of it?

There is an answer here: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string), but he says as an safe example:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$var = mysql_real_escape_string("\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$var' LIMIT 1");`
```

Isn't `mysqli_real_escape_string` already doing the same? he's just specifying what characters should be `mysqli_real_escaped_string`. So how can this all of the sudden become safe? Since it is doing the exact same thing as when you would say:

```
$example = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['exampleVariable']);
```

So how does this:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$var = mysql_real_escape_string("\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$var' LIMIT 1");
```

become safe and this:

```
$example = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['exampleVariable']);
```

not? Isn't he just narrowing down what `mysqli_real_escape_string` would escape, thus making it more vulnerable?

Comment: please read this for further information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Btw I think this question is not at all a duplicate of the one referenced. This question asked about manual escaping instead of parameterized queries, which has nothing to do with deprecated fuctions in general, so I'm marking it for being reopened.

Comment: Indeed this is not a duplicate of the why-should-you-not-use-mysql-functions question. I seconded reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, mysqli_real_escape_string() or other proper escaping is actually technically secure, in the end, that's about what parameterized queries do too. However, there is always a however. For example it is only secure if you have quotes around variables. Without quotes it is not. When it's a 1000 line project with one developer, it's probably ok in the first 3 months. Then eventually even that one developer will forget the quotes, because they are not always needed syntactically. Imagine what will happen in a 2 million LOC project with 200 devs, after 5 years.

Similarly, you must not ever forget using your manual escape function. It may be easy first. Then there is a variable that is validated and can only hold a number, so you are sure it's ok to just put it in without escaping. Then you change your mind and change it into a string, because the query is ok anyway. Or somebody else does it after 2 years. And so on. It's not a technical issue. It's a management-ish issue, in the long run, your code will be vulnerable somehow. Hence it is bad practice.

Another point, it's much harder to automatically scan for SQL injection vulnerabilities if manual escaping is in place. Static code scanners can easily find all instances of concatenated queries, but it's very hard for them to correlate previous escaping if there is any. If you use something like parameterized queries, it is straightforward to find sql injections, because all concatenations are potential candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the character set for the connection does not change what `mysqli_real_escape_string()` escapes. But it avoids the multi-byte character bug because it controls how the string is interpreted after the backslash escape characters have been inserted.

Of course, you can avoid any uncertainty by [using query parameters instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).